# Parallel Transport of Metric Tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor

The question is obvious. What is the parallel transport of metric tensor?
How could one define the transportation of metric tensor with an infinitesmall amount in one direction? 
[image: In 2D] 
  [image]

What is $g_{\mu\nu}(x+\delta x,y)$ in terms of $g_{\mu\nu}(x,y)$ in 2D? Or
What is $g_{\mu\nu}(x+\delta x^\alpha)$ in terms of $g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ in 4D?
The confusing thing is that: Since the parallel transport of a vector contains the covariant derivative of the vector and since the metric is compatible, then we get;

$g_{\mu\nu}(x+\delta x^\alpha)=g_{\mu\nu}(x)$

Is this right? Or because we may assume that we are in a locally flat space (may not?), we should use the ordinary derivative of the metric to parallel transport it instead of the covariant derivate. In this case we get,

$g_{\mu\nu}(x+\delta x^\alpha)=U^\alpha \partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}(x)$

This result is different than the first one, because:

$\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial\lambda}\partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}(x)\neq g_{\mu\nu}(x)$

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I'm not sure. Should I parallel-transport this question to [http://math.stackexchange.com/](Mathematics)? :D

Comment: Don't crosspost! Instead you may want to flag for migration.

Comment: No! Not crosspost. Delete here and ask there?

Comment: I got an explanation that parallell transport is a map from tangent spaces at different points that depends on the connection if that helps at all http://math.stackexchange.com/a/716716/68036

Answer (score 2):

See here: https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~serguei/teaching/sr.pdf (page 40)

It pretty much says that you can define parallel transport of a tensor $T^i_j$ in a way such that the scalar $T^i_ju_iu^j$ is the same at any point. The metric tensor ends up being the same when transported, so your first result is true.